# Google Maps: How can I not let the user create a rectangle which has an area more than X?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, area, rectangles

I have set up a google map on my website(localhost) by using javascript. Right now the user can create `circles` or `rectangles` by left or right clicking. The user can also make the rectangle bigger or smaller and the same applies in circles as well.
 I would like the application not to let the user create rectangles which have an area more than X. 
 I managed to achieve this with circles since the area of a circle is defined by its `radius` and `Math.PI`.
 I know that for the rectangle the area is the length of the bottom multiplied by the length of the height.
 However, how can I find this information from latitudes and longitudes of the south west and north east corners?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're aware that the whole concept of a "rectangle" gets a bit fuzzy when you're dealing with non-rectangular coordinates, right?  Near the poles, for example, interpreting the coordinates as most people think of them would get you more of a trapezoid than a rectangle...

Comment: indeed I didn't think of that. So I guess this isn't possible or needs additional information?

Comment: Probably needs more info.  It'd certainly be possible to convert geographical coordinates (roughly) to 3D rectangular (cubic?) ones, but the location of the northwest and southeast corners would depend on how you decide to define your rectangle, i'd think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `P(X1, Y1)` and `Q(X2, Y2)` be the north east and south west coordinates (I suppose that you have converted them to pixels first). The rectangle's area would be then `A = (X2-X1)*(Y2-Y1)`.

Comment: How big are your rectangles? If they are small areas (like a few squared miles) you can calculate them like if they where "flat" areas, otherwise you must calculate a "spherical surface area", like @ksm001 suggested, in order to get a more accurate area. (sorry, I don't have enough privileges for commenting directly on the question).

Comment: my rectangle isn't that big so I guess doing it like you would do in other cases would be a good approximation of the actual area.

However the coordinates are actually real coordinates and not pixels so I'm not sure if your method would work.

Comment: It depends on how you defined the "max area": if the max area is something like "100 squared degrees", then can use this formula, *but convert south and west to "negative" first*. I mean: if P1 is (50N, 60W) then you should set P1=(-60, 50) (N&S> Y axis; E&W > X axis)